# Size of UICollectionView is sometimes wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

Here is my problem: I'm developing a Kodi Remote on iOS (http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=235973) and everything run pretty well (a classic development) but I'm having a behavior that I can't explain.

I have multiple view controllers; in one of them (a UIViewController containing a UICollectionView), I implemented this delegate method :

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize originalSize = [(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout itemSize];
    CGSize collectionViewSize = [collectionView frame].size;

    CGFloat interItemSpacing = [(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacing];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewFlowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)[[self collectionView] collectionViewLayout];
    UIEdgeInsets sectionInset = [collectionViewFlowLayout sectionInset];

    CGFloat usableWidth = (collectionViewSize.width - ((kColumns - 1) * interItemSpacing) - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right);
    CGFloat width =  usableWidth / kColumns;
    CGFloat height = width * originalSize.height / originalSize.width;

    return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
```

I get the collection view frame (bounds is the same, of course, I don't need origin) and it works great. I get on an iPhone 5 simulator 288 width for a no matter height.

BUT, in a copy-paste of the view controller in the storyboard, I get a 304 width. The weirdest behavior is that with FLEX, and after the render, the collection view measures 288 pixels.

The "only" difference is that the first view controller is just pushed, the second is contained in a UITabBarController.

PS : the first screen I'm talking about are the 3rd & 4th screenshots.

If someone has an explication to this, I'll take it ;)

Update 1 :

If I invalidate the collection view layout in - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews, items are correctly drawn BUT there is like a flash because the whole collection view is redrawn (the header & items below).

Comment: How do you define itemSize of your collectionViewLayout?

Comment: With the method above. I have defined in the storyboard a size (100 pixels wide, 160 pixels high) just to have a ratio.

Comment: Try invalidating the layout in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Not working. I already tried. I just find a way :( I removed the constraint margin on the collection view, and add section inset and margin in header. Working like a charm.

Comment: 16pts will be 2 layout margins. Looks like you spotted this, but pretty much just remove any layout you have against margins.

Comment: Found another solution : every UIViewController must have a UINavigationController as parent instead of the UITabBarController. After that, everything works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width,
                        self.collectionView.frame.size.height);
}
```

and uncheck "Constrain to margins" and click on all dotted red constrain
so -8 padding will be gone in iPhone 6+

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Storyboard

It makes a lot of sense when you approach the problem with a `Storyboard`. First, you will get a clear view of what you are designing. Second, you get to build your application with exactly 0 lines of code, leading to 0 bugs.

The parent `UITabBarController` and a set of `UINavigationController` is a common design pattern, and only when you implement it as follow do you get a proper UI behavior.

[image: Storyboard with 1 Nav controller per tab]

## Code

You do not have to use a `Storyboard` to create the hierarchy above. You can embed each `UIViewController` in a `UINavigationController` programatically.

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-32258452) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-32258452).

Comment: How is this related to the question? The link you provided isn't related in any way to the original question. I checked your **Architecture of UITabBarController & embedded UIViewController using UINavigationController** but `UICollectionView` is nowhere to be found in your example.

Comment: See Booby69's comment "Every UIViewController must have a UINavigationController as parent instead of the UITabBarController. After that, everything works correctly"